# Azure KeyVault Key Client returns JSONWebKey on getKey method. How to get private key as blob or buffer?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-keyvault, ssh2-sftp

I'm using the `@azure/keyvault-keys` package to get the `pem` private key I uploaded to the Azure KeyVault. Now I would like to retrieve that and connect to [SFTP](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client) like this

```
return this.sftpClient.connect({
  host,
  port,
  username,
  privateKey: secret.key,
});
```

Where private key is defined as

```
    /** Buffer or string that contains a private key for either key-based or hostbased user authentication (OpenSSH format). */
privateKey?: Buffer | string | undefined;
```

I'm however unable to figure out a way to get the keyvault uploaded `PEM` file as I would locally using

```
privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/path/id_dsa_key.pem'),
```

How can I utilize Azure Key Vault to store my private key and then connect to the SFTP client with this key vault key?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you link the managed identity or set the correct access policies on your keyvault?

Comment: When a private key is held as a key in Key Vault, it cannot be exported in the clear. You could store it as a secret, however, and that would work.

Comment: @MichaelHoward-MSFT that's what we eneded up doing. If you post this as an answer I'll accept the solution, thanks